# How to get directories,subdirectories, files creation date & time from FTP remote Server in C++?

Tags: c++

How to  get directories,subdirectories, files creation date & time from FTP remote Server in C++ ? 
I want to create a FTP client in C++

Comment: RTFM: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CIt doesn't matter the language, Once you are connected to the ftp server, just send the commands following the FTP protocol..

You should check the [File Transfer Protocol RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959)

That is if you want to do an ftp client from scratch. You can use libraries for doing so.

The commands you need, could be `LIST` command. But It is crappy. A new RFC updates the first one and add two new commands that do exactly what you want. Those commands are `MLST` and `MLSD` and you can see the [RFC 3659 here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3659#page-23). You should take care, I think not all ftp servers accept these commands.

One think you can do, is use a sniffer like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to sniff and get info about what commands are used by FTP clients. (BTW: Wireshark filters should be: ftp || ftp-data )

Linux FTP Command uses `LIST` for its dir command.

Comment: @Marco : i want to get creation date and time of files.folders etc...I have created FTP client in C++. I am making use of CFtpConnection for connecting to FTP server.

Comment: In the RFC there is specified the command LIST, but an update added two new commands (MLST and MLSD). Sending those commands you should get the info you want. Those commands are specified in RFC 3659 that updates the first rfc. I will edit my post to add it.

Comment: @Marco : But i am using CFTPsession , CFtpConnection ,GetFtpConnection to connect to FTP and then using CFtpFileFind to find all the files and directories present in server in this case how i can use these above commands to do so or u have any aother FTP c++ client library ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/4tw7dfy6(v=VS.80).aspx

Take a look at the command operator. Use the documentation. The command you should use is "LIST"

My answer was a bit too general. That is the documentation of your particular implementation and has nothing to do with what you have asked! :P

Comment: @Macro :Could you pls provide me some sample example how to make use of this command.

Comment: @Swapnil Gupta
Sorry, I don't have Windows.
Just googled this:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ftp_with_net.aspx?display=Print

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects to it... first you need to select some C++ (or C) socket functions to use to make the connection, then you need to implement the expect send/receive protocol involved with FTP to request and retrieve the directory and file content you're interested in.  (In practice, though you haven't mentioned it, you're probably also interested in writing the retrieved data out somewhere in your own system).

There are many choices re the socket implementation... you can use the BSD socket API or find some precanned C++ API.  How you implement it, or which library might do it well for you, depends greatly on your client architecture: whether it's single- or multi-threaded, retrieving one file at a time or downloading hundreds in parallel.

For FTP, the RFC document specifying the exchange protocol can easily be found searching the 'net, but will be considerable work to implement well from scratch.

Alternatively, you can find a library that already implements the FTP protocol, and wrap it into an application.  It's not clear from your question exactly what you consider to be "creating a client", so this may or may not count.

Of course, there are dozens of simple ftp clients you could download for sample code, especially if you count C implementations that would build and can be customised in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Libcurl is very useful for this sort of thing:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/

Comment: Guys i want to get creation date and time of files.folders etc...I have created FTP client in C++. I am making use of CFtpConnection for connecting to FTP server.